# import (migration) user database to wp-users

Tags: database, users, migration, bulk-import

I am having hard time for importing to user-meta and post-meta from my non-wp-tables. I am trying to do db migration from user table and post table to WordPress tables.

So it might be

- user table to wp-users and wp-usermeta
- post table to wp-posts and wp-postmeta

I have been trying to find good plugins but it's all limited. (only basic information)

My old user table has all of users information on **only 1 row (1 line)** such as `phone number, mobile, DOB..` etc. These have to be on user-meta table.

Old user tables and wp-users are on same database now.

How can I insert user information from old user table to wp-user(for basic information) and wp-usermeta (for extra information)?

Is it possible to make it with PHP coding? (because it's on same database) 
I am trying to figure it out how to do with php coding or something else.

If anyone knows can you advise me a sample coding? 
or anybody knows any good plugins? all of them I found are not enough to put all of user information.

Answer (score 0):

1. get all data from DB1( non-wp-database ) and save to an **$array**.
2. Use this wordpress code inside your **functions.php** for insert users into DB2 ( wordpress database).

```
function cxg_wp_insert_user() {
    foreach ( $array as $arr ) {
        $user_data = array(
        'ID' => '',
        'user_pass' => wp_generate_password(),
        'user_login' => $loginName,
        'user_nicename' => $nicename,
        'user_url' => '',
        'user_email' => $eMail,
        'display_name' => $displayName,
        'nickname' => '$nickname,
        'first_name' => $firstName,
        'role' => get_option('default_role')
        }
    );
    $user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'cxg_wp_insert_user' );
 3. After updating disable this function
```

NOTE : For more details about insert user goto [wordpress insert user codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user)

Comment: Thanks, but what about other meta values? phone number1, phone number2, DOB, address... ect.. any instruction or sample source for usermeta or post-meta?